# Jquery ajax call to invoke spring controller?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have below config in web.xml

```
<servlet>  
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
         </init-param>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I have controller as below.

```
 @Controller  
    public class SomeController { 

       @RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showExtendedUi(@RequestParam("geo") String geo, @RequestParam("tab") String tab, @RequestParam("gid") String gid, HttpServletResponse response) {  
        //logic
    } 

    }
```

Now how can i specify URL in jquery ajax call?

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getData.do",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(responseJson) {
                alert("json"+responseJson);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert('Failed to get details: ' + error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just add the data that you're sending It seems that your ajax call is ok just add the request params on the data attr of the call.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code above, you should just be able to go to the following url (assuming 8080 port as default Tomcat port).

```
http://localhost:8080/getData.do?geo=1&tab=1&gid=1
```

This should show you in a browser the JSON you require.  If the JSON appears on the page here, just do `$.getJSON()` from jQuery as it has built in methods for pulling back JSON.  You can see the documentation on this method [here.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: Remember the *.do on the DispatcherServlet mapping it should be "getData.do"

Comment: Edited, although I'm not sure what OP gains by having this in his web.xml

Comment: Neither me that remembers me the pure servlets mapping to .do but there is no need to have it i always have "/" as servlet mapping xD